# Return the active window title in java

Tags: ubuntu, groovy

Using On linux using java/groovy I wish to retrieve the name of the active window and store it in a string, but I can't get my command to work - this just returns an empty string.

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import javax.swing.JFrame

curText = "xdotool getwindowname \$(xdotool getwindowfocus)".execute().text

new SwingBuilder().edt { optionPane().showMessageDialog(null, '#'+curText+'#') }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the command in two rather than trying to do both in one `execute()` made it work for me:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import javax.swing.JFrame

id = "xdotool getwindowfocus".execute().text
curText = "/usr/bin/xdotool getwindowname $id".execute().text

new SwingBuilder().edt { optionPane().showMessageDialog(null, '#'+curText+'#') }
```

In this case, in a groovyConsole, I got:

```
#GroovyConsole
#
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant - works a charm. I'd tried the same but not realised you didn't need the brackets.

Comment: The `$(<command>)` syntax in BASH means that the command inside it will be evaluated before the outer command, and the result put in its place. In this case, we're doing that in the groovy script and holding it in `id` rather than using the BASH substitution. If this answer helped you, don't forget to upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer! :)

Comment: I had already tried to up vote  it, but haven't got enough reputation yet, so you might have to wait for a little while. Sorry

Comment: No worries,  thanks for the answer acceptance anyway. I know how you feel about the lack of reputation... It's very limiting but for obvious good reasons!